# Как изменить формат поля в ArсGIS?

Tags: python, замена

Поле *!direction!* содержит данные типа

*N 23-45-45 W*

Нужно привести данные к такому виду

*СЗ 23º45'45"*

```
!direction!.replace("N",u"С") and !direction!.replace("W",u"З")
```

заменяет выборочно.

Помогите решить проблему. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логические операции не предназначены для управления потоком выполнения. В приведённом вами выражении выполняются обе замены, обе возвращают строку, над которыми выполняется логическая операция AND, в результате которой у вас остаётся одна из строк, и именно она трактуется, как значение. Можно решить задачу так:

```
tt = str.maketrans('NWSE', 'СЗЮВ')
translated = !direction!.translate(tt)
tokens = translated.split(' ')
tokens[1] = '{}º{}\'{}"'.format(*tokens[1].split('-'))
print('{0}{2} {1}'.format(*tokens))
```

**UPDATE:**

ArcGIS использует код введённый в калькулятор поля как лямбду, а лямбда не может иметь состояний и побочных эффектов, она может только вернуть какое-то значение. К тому же применяется Python 2.7. Придётся нагородить вырвиглазный однострочник:

```
u''.join((u''.join(t) for t in zip(u'{0}{2} {1}'.format(*(!direction!.replace(u'N', u'С').replace(u'W', u'З').replace(u'S', u'Ю').replace(u'E', u'В').split(u' '))).split(u'-'), u'º\'"')))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Проблема решена.